# Preorder traversal for Nary trees

Tags: java, tree

I'm still a beginner to Java. I've just learned about binary search trees and the idea of preorder traversals, and how you'd be able to use recursion to implement preorder traversal of a binary tree. Something like this:

```
Void preorder(node root){
if(root==null){//base case when node becomes null we stop recursive function
return ;}
System.out.print(root.data+" ");// printing the value of node as first time we visit
Preorder(root.left);// look at left side of tree ,once left side complete
Preorder(root.right);// start having a look at right side of that specific node
}
```

However, how could this same recursive model be implemented for a N ary tree? one in which the number of children per node isn't necessarily 2? cause then the .left and .right wouldn't be applicable, no? Please lmk if more code needs to be provided, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having only two children, the tree can have n children. So you need to model the children as a list, e.g. an `ArrayList`:

```
class Node {
    String data;
    List<Node> children = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addChild(Node node) {
        this.children.add(node);
    }
    
}
```

Then iterate over the children in the preorder traversal:

```
void preorder(Node node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return;
    }
    System.out.print(node.data + " ");
    for (Node child : node.children) {
        preorder(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would it be possible to merge the two portions of code together? As in giving the preorder method a second parameter that would be the arraylist children? How would the recursion work then?

Comment: @Ides784 you mean passing the children to the method like `preorder(root, root.children);` ? Why would you do that? You can already access the children from the first parameter.